# How to combine columns into one column ignoring NAs (data.table)

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table like below. I want to merge two columns A and B into one but excluding the missing values (if exists)

```
dt <- data.table("title"=c("A", "B", NA, "D"), 
             "sha"=c("1", NA, "3", NA),
             "date" = c("1/1/2020","1/2/2020","1/3/2020","1/4/2020$"))
```

the result for the new column should be like

```
new
A1
B
3
D
```

I want to implement it in data.table. looking for something like dplyr::coalesce

Comment: Should the 3rd element be `C3`.  Try `dt[, new := title][!is.na(sha), new := paste0(new, sha)]`

Comment: I edited the question. what if I have multiple columns to check if they are not NA before combining them together

Comment: You can use `unite` with `na.rm` i.e. `library(tidyr); dt[, unite(.SD, new, title, sha, na.rm = TRUE, sep = "", remove = FALSE)]`

Answer (score 2):

With two columns, we may either use `fifelse` or create a column with the 'title' and then use indexing in `i` based on non-NA elements to `paste`

```
library(data.table)
dt[, new := title][!is.na(sha), new := paste0(new, sha)]
```

If there are multiple columns, one option is also with `unite` with `na.rm = TRUE` to remove the `NA` elements

```
library(tidyr)
dt[, unite(.SD, new, title, sha, na.rm = TRUE, sep = "", remove = FALSE)]
```

Or use `do.call` with `paste` after replacing the `NA` with `""`

```
nm1 <- c('title', 'sha')
dt[, new := do.call(paste, c(lapply(.SD, \(x)
     replace(x, is.na(x), "")), sep="")),.SDcols = nm1]
```